# Restore lost keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys

I lost my shortkeys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>⇐</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>⇒</kbd> for [juxtaposing my windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-tiled.html):  how can I retrieve them?

I have installed *Unity Tweak Tool*, which made my Ubuntu freeze many times (with the snap option), but these keyboard shortcuts aren't specified.

Ideally I would like to edit the file where these shortcuts are defined.

I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Please correct your title

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution : install CompizConfig, section *window manager*, and check **grid** box.

Answer (score 0):

These shortcuts are present in "Keyboard" option in "System Settings" or you may search for "keyboard" in "dash". Four shortcuts for navigation are defined there, on changing which you may get back old ones.

Comment: no, in _keyboard>shortcuts>windows_ there are nothing like "optimize windows on the **half** left/right"... there are for optimize/minimize for all the screen

Answer (score 0):

You could use terminal if you wanted. 
Open a terminal use the command

```
 gconftool -u "/$entry"
```

Comment: Would be useful if you could provide actual/example entries to be removed :)

Comment: You are correct, I would add them but I am unsure of what exactly they are named. gconftool -u "/$entry" was suppost to "Unset" all of the keybindings BUT maybe what your looking for is (gconftool -u "/apps/gnome_settings_daemon/keybindings/navigation), if this doesn't help. Maybe you could try installing gconf-editor (sudo apt-get install gconf-editor) open it up and try changing settings in (apps->metacity->global_keybindings) or (apps->metacity->keybinding_commands) Hope this helps, sorry I couldn't find the exact thing you are looking for.